# Add an android widget to the Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, widgets

I'd love a scrollable widget that displayed the feed, possibly customising what was shown (i.e. hot questions, unanswered, rep changes, badge notifications etc.) globally or per-site.

Ideally each entry would be clickable in the widget, opening up the SE app to the relevant screen.

Comment: It would also be nice to have a widget that displayed inbox notification count.

Comment: I'd suggest something like the one for plume that can flip between 2 lists. One would be the feed, the other the notifications list.

Comment: My preference would be something smallish like a User card [link](Flair™: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213798/rhughes/flair ) which shows one chosen profile or an accumulation of all your profiles. To make it useful, it would be cool to expand it with a notification counter or a 'reputation delta' like the stock exchange (see what I did there?).

Comment: Related feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224343/200868