# Add a widget that displays Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hot-questions, widgets

The Hot Network Questions shown on the sidebar on every site are quite interesting and a widget that displays them would be a nice addition to the app.

The list could be randomised and show only a small set of questions every time. On refreshing the widget or after fixed time intervals, the set of questions could be changed.

This is related to the [existing feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194295/200868).

Comment: This is a really cool idea. We're currently toying around with ideas for widgets but nothing's definite yet so I'm not yet going to give this a [status-planned]

Comment: Isn't this [status-completed] now? `:)`